# Max number from a set of data

Tags: matlab, max

I want to get the maximum value of three consecutive numbers using the data below, starting with the first three numbers in this case 50.0, 50.0 and 42.8 then store it in another Nx1 matrix, then pick the second next three numbers, 50.0, 42.8 and 48.2, get the maximum and store it in the second row of the Nx1 matrix, then pick the next three numbers 42.8, 48.2 and 46.4 get the max value and store it in the third row of the Nx1 matrix and so on to the last data (57.2). I will appreciate any help in this direction.

```
50.0
50.0
42.8
48.2
46.4
46.4
55.4
71.6
71.6
69.8
51.8
57.2
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry! I am using matlab

Comment: value = 50.0
50.0
42.8
48.2
46.4
46.4
55.4
71.6
71.6
69.8
51.8
57.2

for a = 1:11
     result[a] = max(value[a], value[a+1], value[a+2]);
end

result
when i run this code i get this error message "Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis
or bracket."

Comment: it's because in matlab you use ( ) not [ ] to reach a vector's or matrix's element and when you build an array then use [ ]

Comment: When i ran the code this is what i got:    res =

    50


res =

   50.0000   48.2000


res =

   50.0000   48.2000   71.6000


res =

   50.0000   48.2000   71.6000   69.8000

Comment: this is what i was expecting 50.0 50.0 48.2 48.2 55.4 55.4 71.6 71.6 71.6 69.8 57.2 57.2

Comment: oh ... sorry, i misunderstood ... one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
clc
array = [50.0 50.0 42.8 48.2 46.4 46.4 55.4 71.6 71.6 69.8 51.8 57.2];
res = [];
len = length(array);
for i = 1 : len-2
    m = max([array(i) array(i+1) array(i+2)]);
    res = [res m];
end
m = max([array(len) array(len-1)]);
res = [res m m]
```

the result sould be in the `res` variable

Comment: Thank you very much. Such a leap for me. I just figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Stack rows with NaNs (not a number) as placeholders, then take the max across columns:

```
a = [50.0 50.0 42.8 48.2 46.4 46.4 55.4 71.6 71.6 69.8 51.8 57.2];
A = a
A(end+1,:) = [a(2:end),NaN]
A(end+1,:) = [a(3:end),NaN,NaN]
max(A)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Such a leap for me.

Comment: Thanks. You guys are the best!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As in R2016a, there is a function called [movmax](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmax.html) that does exactly what you want to achieve:

```
a = [50.0 50.0 42.8 48.2 46.4 46.4 55.4 71.6 71.6 69.8 51.8 57.2];
movmax(a,[0 2]) %
```

Parameters are: `0` number on the left of the pivotal element where the computation is made, and `2` on the right (+ the pivotal element, meaning a 3 element vector on with the max is calculated)

> ans = 50.0000   50.0000   48.2000   48.2000   55.4000   71.6000   71.6000   71.6000   71.6000   69.8000   57.2000   57.2000

---

This might be a job for `arrayfun`

```
res = arrayfun(@(x) max(a(x:min(x+2,length(a)))), 1:length(a))
```

where

```
a = [50.0 50.0 42.8 48.2 46.4 46.4 55.4 71.6 71.6 69.8 51.8 57.2];
```

`arrayfun` is used here to do some loops in a single matlab command. The trick to get the expected result is to take the minimum between the length of the input vector and the internal index, so that the index does not exceed the length of the vector.

The result:

> res =
>      50.0000   50.0000   48.2000   48.2000   55.4000   71.6000   71.6000   71.6000   71.6000   69.8000   57.2000   57.2000

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you use [`im2col`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) to generate overlapping blocks of your data as columns of a matrix, and then apply [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) along the first dimension:

```
x = [50.0 50.0 42.8 48.2 46.4 46.4 55.4 71.6 71.6 69.8 51.8 57.2].'; %'// data
N = 3; %// block size
xi = im2col([x(:); NaN(N-1,1)], [N 1]); %// append N-1 NaNs to generate the last blocks
result = max(xi, [], 1).';
```

In the example, this gives

```
result =
   50.0000
   50.0000
   48.2000
   48.2000
   55.4000
   71.6000
   71.6000
   71.6000
   71.6000
   69.8000
   57.2000
   57.2000
```

Comment: Thanks. You guys are the best!